# error installing tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat

```
Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed.
● tomcat7.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat7; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-05-19 15:57:48 EDT; 5ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2929 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 19 15:57:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
May 19 15:57:48 ubuntu tomcat7[2929]:  * no JDK or JRE found - please set J...ME
May 19 15:57:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Control process exited,...=1
May 19 15:57:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
May 19 15:57:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 19 15:57:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Failed with result 'exi...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package tomcat7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up authbind (2.1.1+nmu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tomcat7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i tried upgrade and restart to.pls help me with this issue .Thanks

Comment: This is why `* no JDK or JRE found - please set J...ME`, is your java jdk set?

Comment: When you run `java --version` what do you see?

Comment: Also check 

   update-alternatives --display java

The tomcat7-common should have required a JRE to be installed, make sure that at least one of the following packages is installed.
    `default-jre-headless`
    `openjdk-8-jre`
    `openjdk-8-jre-headless`

It will be located under  the following directory if it is installed:

    `/usr/lib/jvm/`